# How to return source documents when using LangChain Expression Language (LCEL)?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, langchain, py-langchain, retrieval-augmented-generation

Most samples of using [LangChain's Expression Language](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/) (LCEL) look like this:

```
chain = setup_and_retrieval | prompt | model | output_parser
```

How can I access the `source_documents` in a RAG application when using this expression language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well for me:

```
rag_chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(source_documents=condense_question | retriever)
    | RunnablePassthrough.assign(context=lambda inputs: format_docs(inputs["source_documents"]) if inputs["source_documents"] else "")
    | RunnablePassthrough.assign(prompt=qa_prompt)
    | RunnablePassthrough.assign(response=lambda inputs: llm(inputs["prompt"].messages))
)
```

It's called like this:

```
response_dict = rag_chain.invoke({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
ai_msg = response_dict["response"]
source_documents = response_dict["source_documents"]
```

The way that helped me understand how to do it was this:

1. You initially pass a dictionary into the chain (in my case with the keys `question` and `chat_history`).
2. Every time you use `RunnablePassthrough.assign`, you can ADD stuff to that dictionary and then pass that on to the next step.
3. `RunnablePassthrough.assign` always RETURNS a dictionary.

This is what happens in my code example:

1. We use `RunnablePassthrough.assign` to add a new `source_documents` key to the dictionary. Its value is the result of calling the `condense_question` function (defined elsewhere) that builds and returns a condenser chain. Its condensed result is passed into our retriever (also defined elsewhere).
2. We use `RunnablePassthrough.assign` to add a new `context` key to the dictionary. Its value is the result of calling a `format_docs` method (defined elsewhere) that combines the source_documents into a single context string.
3. We use `RunnablePassthrough.assign` to add a new `prompt` key to the dictionary. Its value is the result of calling `qa_prompt`, which is defined as `qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(...)`.
4. We use `RunnablePassthrough.assign` one more time to add a new `response` key to the dictionary. Its value is the result of actually calling the llm with the messages from our prompt.
5. The chain returns a dictionary with all the keys we've added along the way. The `response` key contains the LLM's response as an `AIMessage`, and the `source_documents` key contains the source documents.

I'm sure this can be done in a more concise way, but this worked for me and I can understand it :)